# How should one link to a jQuery library: always link to the latest library or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happened is that we have a page that was previously working then all of sudden some scripts no longer work (for some reason). We figured out that we needed to use the latest jQuery library to fix the problem.

So we were thinking to just link to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js so that it's always updated.

However, we are also aware that if we will always use the latest jQuery library, the new version might cause some problems on other older scripts.

What is the best way to link the jQuery library then to minimize these types of issues?

Comment: I think using/linking latest 'specific' version for that time is the best thing to do. Like you said, pointing to `jquery-latest.min.js` will most likely break your previous/existing codes since existing jquery codes are often deprecated and replaced by another in the next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the stable version of the library to your local/server and link to it. That's all.

It is a bad idea to link to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Jquery latest version always available in,

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
```

For Latest Min Jquery, use

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

To get latest jquery from other hosts, follow [jquerylatest.com](http://jquerylatest.com)